# Update column value to NULL based on $_POST values for both columns?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Trying to update a column (`$_POST['dtf']`) value to null based on another columns value (`$_POST['pid']`), but its not working. I have tried different versions of the MySQL statement but with no avail.
**AJAX**

```
      $(function() {
      $(".remove-tf").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'tf-delete.php',
          data: 'pid=' + $(".pid").attr("value") + '&dtf=' + $(this).val()
      });
      });
      });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
include 'sqlconnection.php';
$conn = OpenCon();
$sql = "UPDATE tasks SET '".$_POST['dtf']."'=NULL WHERE pid=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['pid']);
if ($stmt->execute()){
    header('Location: listings.php');
};
$stmt->close();
CloseCon($conn);
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" class="pid" name="pid" value="">
<button class="remove-tf" name="submit" type="button" value="taskimg0">Remove</button>
```

Comment: `$(".remove-tf").attr("value")` will be the value of the first `.remove-tf` element in the DOM, not the one that the user clicked on.

Comment: You should use `$(this).val()` to get the clicked element's value.

Comment: And `$(".pid").attr("value")` should be `$(this).prev(".pid").val()`

Comment: @Suboptimizer He's using a prepared statement. But you can't use a placeholder for column names.

Comment: why `$(this).prev(".pid").val()`? can I not just get the value of the element based on its class name? they are not directly next to each other in my real code

Comment: how do i structure the statement so that i can set the column value to the $_POST value?

Comment: You have the column name wrapped in single quotes '".$_POST['dtf']."' change it to ".$_POST['dtf']."

Answer (score 1):

This is your code:

```
$sql = "UPDATE tasks SET '".$_POST['dtf']."' = NULL WHERE pid = ?";
```

This produce a query like:

```
UPDATE tasks set 'foo' = null where pid = ?
```

This is not valid MySQL. The column name should not be be surrounded with single quotes (in ANSI SQL, single quotes are there for strings litterals).

Just change your code to:

```
$sql = "UPDATE tasks SET ".$_POST['dtf']." = NULL WHERE pid = ?";
```

Or if you want to use quoted identifiers, use backticks:

```
$sql = "UPDATE tasks SET `".$_POST['dtf']."` = NULL WHERE pid = ?";
```